# Subclassing UICollectionView, skipping indexes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was trying to subclass collection view layout , in order to get a constant spacing between vertical cells. i have 2 columns and many rows, with dynamic cells height .
The goal is `Pinterest` like grid.

So i have subclassed the layout class, and now has a constant space between cells, but there is a serious problem caused by that .

When i scroll down, the left cells are not being loaded in time= there are many "holes" so that there is blank space of 3-4 cells, and than- they suddenly appears at once -lately.
so i have this :

```
1 2
3 4
  6
  8
```

than 5 and 7 appears when i scroll down more . i just can't get rid of this !

**EDIT:** seems that when all cells are in the same size, this will not happens ,so when i return here a constant height :

```
//cell size
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
     CGSize size=CGSizeMake( imageWidth,  scale*height+[Globals sharedGlobals].gridViewStripHeight );
return size;
```

My subclass(which when not using it, also solves the problem )

```
//the subclass
    - (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        NSArray* arr = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
        for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* atts in arr)
        {
            if (nil == atts.representedElementKind)
            {
                NSIndexPath* ip = atts.indexPath;
                atts.frame = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:ip].frame;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

    - (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* atts =[super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

         if (indexPath.item == 0 || indexPath.item == 1) // degenerate case 1, first item of section
             return atts;

        NSIndexPath* ipPrev =
        [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.item-2 inSection:indexPath.section];

        CGRect fPrev = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:ipPrev].frame;
        CGFloat rightPrev = fPrev.origin.y + fPrev.size.height + 50;
        if (atts.frame.origin.y <= rightPrev) // degenerate case 2, first item of line
            return atts;

        CGRect f = atts.frame;
        f.origin.y = rightPrev;
        atts.frame = f;
        return atts;
    }
```

To use it i have :

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[TopAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init]; subclass
    CGRect  size=CGRectMake( ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-collectionWidth)/2,
                            upperLineMargin, collectionWidth, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-upperLineMargin);
    self.GridView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:size collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [self.GridView registerClass:[GridCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Comment: Straight away I noticed: UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[TopAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init]; 

Should be: TopAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[TopAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init]; 

Doubt this is the problem though.

Comment: @CW0007007 thanks i changed that. see my edit, have you seen something like this ? i just can't find any solution .